# Using endfloat and caption packages to remove caption from figures

Tags: captions, endfloat

In the current example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=6.7in,textheight=9.125in]{geometry} % alter dimensions of document
\usepackage{graphicx} % include graphics i.e. figures
\usepackage[nomarkers,tablesfirst,notablist]{endfloat} %place figures at end of document

\begin{document}
\title{LaTeX Example}
\maketitle
This is an example of a latex document with figures and tables included. 

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|p{3.5in}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Places to Go Backpacking}\\ \hline
Name&Driving Time&Notes\\
&(hours)&\\ \hline
Big Basin&1.5&Very nice overnight to Berry Creek Falls from
either Headquarters or ocean side.\\ \hline
Sunol&1&Technicolor green in the spring. Watch out for the cows.\\ \hline
Henry Coe&1.5&Large wilderness nearby suitable for multi-day treks.\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is my first table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{Figure1}
\caption{Here I describe the figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have a documnet that has a table and a figure. I use the `endfloat` package to place these at the end of the document where the table is placed first followed by a list of figures and finally the figures themselves. Is there a method for removing the captions from the figures but keeping the caption to the table? By adding an option that removes the caption, it does so for both the figure and the table (I don't want this). To remove only the figure caption, the `endfloat` manual states to use the `caption` package:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=none,labelformat=empty,textformat=empty}
```

However, this generates an error, making me think that this command cannot be used with the `endfloat` package. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: What error do you get when using the caption package? If I use your example document, and add `\usepackage{caption}` and `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` it works fine here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control the caption with `\@makecaption` and the `endfloat` package lets you do things at the beginning of the tables `\AtBeginTables` and the beginning of the figures `\AtBeginFigures`. Putting the two together gives:

```
\makeatletter
\let\orig@makecaption\@makecaption
\AtBeginTables{\let\@makecaption\orig@makecaption}
\AtBeginFigures{\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. How could I also remove the page numbering from the list of figures? Or should this be a separate question?

Comment: @Kate just like it says in the endfloat manual: \renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{
\setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}
\noindent\hspace*{1.5em}#1\hfil\newline }